# Creating and Appending DOM Objects From a List of Strings Values in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm confused and I'm not sure where my knowledge of jQuery is breaking down. Can anyone explain why this doesn't work? (I've set up a [JSFiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/kooshmoose/3cYaW/1/) to make it easier to jump right in)

Given the HTML:

```html
<ul id="MyList"></ul>
```

and the Javascript string:

```js
var itemString = "Item1,Item2,Item3";
```

Why does the following method of appending strings as LI objects not work (The error reported is NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8):

```js
aStrings = itemString.split(",");
aLi = $.map($.makeArray(aStrings), function(x) {
    return $("<li>").text(x);
});
$("#MyList").append(aLi);
```

Using $.each() works (following example), but what is wrong with my understanding of the $.map method?

```js
aStrings = itemString.split(",");
$.each(aStrings, function(i, x) {
  $("MyList").append($("<li>").text(x));
});
```

Is my array, aLi, not a true collection of LI DOM elements?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really no reason to even wrap the simple html you are wanting in jQuery within the mapping. It creates extra unnecessary function calls. Also, `aStrings` is already an array making it unnecessary to use `$.makeArray()`

Try this:

```
   aStrings = itemString.split(",");
   aLi = $.map(aStrings, function(x) {
        return  "<li>" + x +"<li>";
   }).join('');

   $("#MyList").append(aLi);
```

`$.map` returns an array of strings which `join()` then changes to a single string which then gets appended

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3cYaW/2/

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery docs:

> **Description:** Pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return values.

You're not using it on a matched set, i.e. `$('someSelector').map(function{}).doSomethingWithReturnedJQueryObject()`. If you had the items in one list and wanted to move them to a different list you could use the map function, but I don't think it's intended to be used in the way you do in your non-working example.

In other words: The `map()`function is intended to be used in the exact opposite manner in which you are attempting to use it here. You could use it to get the contents of each `<li>` and build the index1,index2,index3 string from it.

Comment: Haha. Sorry. OK, that's kinda confusing of jQuery to have two such different functions with almost identical signatures. After having read that page I agree with the answer @charlietfl gave.

Comment: there are a few jQuery methods such as `map` and `each` that can be used different ways. Has to do with jQuery internal usage also.